# Inheritance and INotifyPropertyChanged

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have the following class :

```
public MyClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

private short _evaluation = 0;
        public short Evaluation
        {
            get
            {
                return _evaluation;
            }
            set
            {
                if (_evaluation != value)
                {
                    _evaluation = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("Evaluation");
                }
            }
        }

protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
            }
        }
}
```

This was binded to my wpf datagrid and worked fine as expected (once one value of my table is changed it was refreshed in the datagrid).

But I wanted to improve myClass adding inheritance :

```
public class MyClass2 : MyClass
{

}
public class MyClass3 : MyClass
{

}
public class MyBindingObject
{
public MyClass2 Stats {get;set;}
}
```

in my UC :

```
public ObservableCollection<MyBindingObject> _Data;
public void LoadData()
{
        this.DataContext = this;
        this.dataGrid1.ItemsSource = null;
        this.dataGrid1.Items.Clear();

        int i = 0;
        _Data = new ObservableCollection<MyBindingObject>();
        while (i < staticVariable.myList)
        {
                _Data.Add(staticVariable.myList[i]);
            i++;
        }

        this.dataGrid1.ItemsSource = _Data;
        this.dataGrid1.Cursor = Cursors.Hand;
}
```

the column :

```
<DataGridTextColumn Width="50" Binding="{Binding Stats.Evaluation}" IsReadOnly="True" />
```

The only properties which are binded to the datagrid are on MyClass. But with this the propertychanged doesn't seem to work anymore.
I noticed the values are changed when I scroll my datagrid only.

Is there a way to improve my solution to make it work ? (the idea is to not refresh all the datagrid manualy).

Thank you

Comment: There isn't enough information to guess what could be wrong. The way you describe it, it should work. Could you provide a [minimal complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: per your added code, you may also have to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` for `MyBindingObject` to notify when the property `Stats` is changed. I doubt that `ObservableCollection` does not support notifying property change for 1 level deeper properties (in this case the level 1 is `Stats`, but you're binding to level 2 at `Evaluation`)

Comment: if you do a real UC then you sould not do something like this: this.DataContext = this; you should look at dependency properties